# angular 2 display div when checkbox checked

Tags: angular

I'm using an array of questions as model:

```
questions: Question[] = [];
```

I'm printing a list of checkbox with the question array in the side of the page. Now when checking a checkbox I want a div with the question info to be displayed on the page. How can I communicate the checked_div array with the questions array to show/hide the divs when checkbox are or not checked?

Comment: and what you have tried so far

Comment: is it angular or angular js?

Comment: i've edited the question, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your code or the structure of your `Question`class I would recommend to bind your checkboxes to a `[ngModel]` and show your div with a ngIf. I assume as following (for Angular 2+):

**Question class:**

```
class Question {
  question: string;       // the question
  visible: boolean;       // is the div visible or not
  answers: Array<String>; // an array with answers
}
```

**Go through the question array**

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions">
  <input type="checkbox" ([ngModel])="question.visible">
  <div class="question-info" *ngIf="question.visible">
    // Question Info
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats what I were looking for!! Thanks @ma-kobi so much